# Bootstrap Loading State Ajax Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Issue getting the 'loading' state to remain until the ajax has received the response from a php script.  The 'Loading' works initially, remains for about a second, then disappears, and then resets after the response.  Wanting to have the Button remain the "Loading..." until the PHP script is finished.

Html:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-info" id="parse_all" data-loading-text="Loading...">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
    <span>Parse All Data</span>
</button>
<div id="parse_resp"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
$('#parse_all').click(function() {
    var btn = $(this)
    btn.button('loading');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "parse_all.php",
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(response){
            btn.button('reset');
            $("#parse_resp").html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The reset is according to your code running once PHP-script is finished, please provide the PHP-code aswell and please elaborate what you mean with "until PHP script is finished"?

Comment: Hi Adrian, the PHP is returning an echo statement that lets the user know that the mysql has finished updating.  #parse_resp will show this.  I'm wondering that the loading state is timed, as I've researched and it seems that to be the case, or not?  Basically, can the "Loadding..." remain until the php response is received by Ajax? Then be reset?  Cheers

Comment: Yes it can, and according to your code it will. However if the ajax -call fails or your PHP fails this will not be the case.

Comment: The culprit is: btn-outline, works fine with normal Bootstrap buttons...  Thanks!

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 0):

the Bootstrap loading state seems not be working on buttons with the "btn-outline" class.  Solution: remove the "btn-outline" class.